# Find all files *string*.dat that contain "string1 string2" in the current directory

Tags: cmd, windows-10, findstr

I need to find the string "substring1 substring2" in a datafile of a current directory.
I use the cmd of Windows-10.
I use the following command according the Windows documentation:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr#examples

findstr /c:"hello there" x.y
```

In this way it doesn't find anything, allthough the string is present.
When I use the same instruction without ':'

```
findstr /c:"hello there" x.y
```

it shows me all cases of 'hello' and all cases of 'there'.

Here it is the concrete case:

```
findstr /c: "INVITE sip:" .\*5656*.dat
FINDSTR: Argoment not found after /c
```

Pls. help

Comment: The literal string is case sensitive. Have you tried using the `/I` switch? In the literal case. do not put a SPACE character after `/c:`.

Comment: Thanks. The SPACE character was the problem. But there is still another one with the visualization (look down comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me, so I guess it is an issue of case sensitivity. You might need to add `/i`, like this:

```
findstr /c:"INVITE sip:" /i *5656*.dat
```

You mention `without ':'`, but the command is just like the previous one (maybe you mean no colon after "sip"?). It won't work without the colon in the parameter, the colon in the string works just fine. I am not sure if `findstr` looks for the words separately (*"it shows me all cases of 'hello' and all cases of 'there'"*), I wasn't able to do that. And your final example won't work either because of the extra space after the colon.

In case this does not work at all, are the files in a subfolder? Have you tried simpler terms and then start adding words to the string? Do they have any special characters?

**Update**

Based on your comments, there might be a carriage return character in the outputted string, so what you can do is redirect the console output to a file, and then open that file, preferably with something better than Notepad, like Notepad++.

```
findstr /c:"INVITE sip:" *5656*.dat > results.txt
```

Comment: The problem was the space character after ':'. Now it shows 4 cases in 4 files, as it is the case. But there is still a strange thing left. The files use many special characters. The names of the 1st 2 files are shown correctly like '''name.number.dat''', but the other 2 cases are shown just with non ascii characters. See next comment.

Comment: Ñü óü└¿~Ø×éÉINVITE sip:<phonenumber>;abc@abcdefg.org;user=phone SIP/2.0Æ┤ß:{¬x·┼ÐO5    ║ÇCOMPANYí

Comment: Why and with which command could I visualize it in a normal way?

Comment: Is that the file name or the file contents? If you do `dir *5656*.dat /x` you can check the full name and short 8.3 name of the files. Are they like that? Or is it possible that what you see are the contents of the previous file, and the current file is just displayed on top of that? Try adding `/n` just before `*5656*.dat`.

Comment: The 4 files end with 01,  21, 31 and 41. All the other characters of their names are identical. The shown string in the 1st 2 files is: <Starting from file to file changing special Character>INVITE sip:<phonenumber>;abc@abcdefg.org;user=phone SIP/2.0. But the files 31 and 41 show other special characters after the string, which I cannot see when I open the file with word pad and I search for them.

Comment: Yes they are like that. Adding /n before *5656* doesn't change anything.

Comment: As filenames the last 2 files are visualized like that: Ñü óü└¿~Ø×é

Comment: So nothing weird when using `dir /x`? Can you try findstr specifying file by file? For example, `...*5656*31.dat`. `/n` adds the line number between the file name and the file content. BTW, the file name appears in bold. Are these strange characters bold? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: No, they don't. The first 2 filenames yes, the last 2 not. How do I post a screenshot? It does not work in the comment.

Comment: You can add it to the question, or upload it to a site like Imgur and post the link in a comment. So if you just look for the string in one unique file, you stil don't get the file name? Maybe the outputted text has a carriage return character. I'll update the answer with another idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209408/discussion-between-uwe-98-and-andrew).